# How to convert VB.net Constants to C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am converting VB.Net project to C# in VS2013. I come across a problem in converting constants in VB.NET to C# code and don't want to use the refernce
**using Microsoft.VisualBasic;** in my code. Please suggest me some links for this. check the examples below

**Examples:**

```
For Constants.vbCrLf i use Environment.Newline;
Constants.vbCr = ?
Constants.vbLf = ?
```

**My Code**

```
string[] rows = AllData.Split(Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: `Environment.Newline` isn't necessarily the same as `vbCrLf`. The whole point of that property is to reflect the correct line ending for the environment that you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
string AllData = @"I'm
a 
multi-line
string";

string[] rows = AllData.Split('\r', '\n');
```

or like this:

```
string[] rows2 = AllData.Split( System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray() );
```

The question is, do you really want to split them separately ? 
Splitting them together is an equally bad idea. 
I'd recommend to split only after you've normalized line endings, because Unix/Linux/Mac (POSIX in general) don't use \r\n, they only use \n:

```
string AllData = @"I'm
a 
multi-line
string";

AllData = AllData.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
string[] rows = AllData.Split('\n');
```

If you don't normalize, you won't get lines if the string was composed on Linux/Mac.

```
string[] rows = AllData.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Alternatively, you can split both, and remove empty entries:

```
string[] rows = AllData.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Depends a little bit on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for such constants in C#, since they are character literals: `\r` and `\n`, respectively.

`Environment.Newline` isn't *really* CRLF (`\r\n` in C#) - it's environment dependent. Sometimes it's what you want, sometimes it isn't.

**EDIT:**

To address your newly posted sample code, you could use this:

```
var rows = AllData.Split(new [] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Only you know whether `"\r\n"` or `Environment.NewLine` is the better option - if your input data is environment dependent, use `Environment.NewLine`. If it's supposed to always be `"\r\n"`, use that.

Comment: I added sample code please check the code and suggest me what i have to modify.